# What are the basic techniques for securing my php application?

Tags: php, security, web-applications

So far I practice sanitizing any and all $_GET/$_POST input, and always calling the php file name in an action request, as opposed to PHP_SELF. But I know there's more, and it's kind of scattered all around the web.

I would appreciate any basic tips for php security, and was hoping this question could serve as a one-stop venue for anyone looking for the standard security measures necessary for developing an internet application.

Comment: You should learn about what kind of attacks your web app can be vulnerable to. Then learn how you can stop your app from being vulnerable (to that specific attack).

Comment: yes, you always secure your city against a threat, and you must know the threats

Comment: navnav, feel free to elaborate in an answer. You seem to know just what I'm looking for.

Comment: OWASP enumerates many types of common vulnerabilities. Check out the [top ten list](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project), and the [PHP top 5](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Top_5) for starters.

Comment: Read the "Security" section of this post: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development

Comment: How is this question ambiguous in the least? List the most common security measures taken in php. You know what that means. And a lot of people could benefit from this. I'm surprised no one had the decency to keep this alive, or at least move it to where it could stand without being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better approach than escaping every user input with mysql_real_escape_string is to use prepared statements.

You can read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

With prepared statements you are both fast and secure. Fast, because they are prepared once and executed many times. Secured, because they are so immune to SQL Injection attacks.

Another type of attacks are Cross-Site Request Forgery attacks. Many PHP frameworks already are prepared for this kind of problems, and solve it in one way or another. If you are using a framework, you should check if it provides csrf defense. If you are working without framework you should start to read about this kind of attacks.

Last but not least, there are XSS type of attacks (Cross-Site Scripting). It is connected with improper escaping of user input in javasript. Attacker could stole some important data from your users. So you also should protect against this kind of attack. Look here: http://phpmaster.com/php-security-cross-site-scripting-attacks-xss/

These are basics kind of attacks. If you can prevent them then you more secure that 80% of the web.

Comment: Thank you for your humble answer, sebast.

Answer (score 1):

If a script is interacting with a database server, all queries sent to this server must be escaped to avoid [sql injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). A lot of demage can be done if this security measure is not taken, but fortunatly it is quite simple to escape a string as the functions already exist in php. 
For a MySQL database it is [`mysql_real_escape_string(string $unescaped_string [, resource $link_identifier ])`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Here is an example how it works:

Script: index.php?user=**'; TRUNCATE TABLE users; SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '**

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user']);
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '$user'"); //The table users won't be truncated
```